# Imagemagick (convert) console vs php Imagick - different results

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

[image: png]

[image: jpg result on console]

when I doing `convert 1.png 1.jpg` - I got removed transparent from png and see real backgound in jpg,
but when I doing the same in php Imagick:

```
    $piece = new Imagick("1.png");
    $piece->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
    $piece->setImageFormat('jpg'); // How to refresh content of $piece w/o save to disk?
    $piece->writeImage('image.jpg'); // it works as I need - when reopen saved image
```

I got just white background where was transparent as on first image (but on first it's transparent).

How I can get the same result with Imagick?

Comment: Well... you're just instantiating `Imagick` objects? See [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php) for examples of how to use it.

Comment: no, next I doing `$canvas2->cropimage(268, 150, 0, 0);
  $jpg = $canvas2->writeImage('image.jpg');` and in image.jpg result with white backgound

Comment: Please edit your question with all relevant code then (don't just post it in comments).

Comment: updated, now another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing two different types of processing.

JPG does not support transparency. So your convert command is just reading the PNG input and saving to JPG output. The alpha channel with the transparency is simply removed showing whatever image or color data was under the transparent part of the alpha channel.

In your Imagick code, you are flattening the alpha channel against the default white background. That puts white where the alpha channel was transparent and then saves to JPG.

If you want the same white in your convert command then do `convert image.png -flatten image.jpg`. If you want your Imagick to do the same as your convert, then remove the flattening. Read the input.png image and simply save to JPG.